# Error installing Cinelerra GG on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: package-management, repository

I am following this instructions:
https://www.cinelerra-gg.org/ubuntu-package/ which requires to do:

`sudo apt-add-repository https://cinelerra-gg.org/download/pkgs/ub20`

The error I am getting is:

```
Err:11 https://cinelerra-gg.org/download/pkgs/ub20 focal Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 2606:4700:3035::681b:8f12 443]
Reading package lists... Done
E: The repository 'https://cinelerra-gg.org/download/pkgs/ub20 focal Release'
  does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

What do I need to do to install it? (is perhaps the server down? `404  Not Found [IP: 2606:4700:3035::681b:8f12 443]`)

I tried their [Forum](https://www.cinelerra-gg.org/forum/) to get support, but I am not getting the email verification for a new User - so I can't get help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We got this notice here at Cinelerra-gg.org and will try to do it ourselves to see if there is a problem.

**UPDATE:**  we had no problem installing it.  We believe that you probably just did not edit the file     /etc/apt/sources.list   as shown further down in the instructions.  You have to include in that file the line:

deb [trusted=yes] https://cinelerra-gg.org/download/pkgs/ub20 focal main

If that line in not in the file or correctly in the file, fix it. Then:

sudo apt update

sudo apt install cin